# Transferring Image (Downloaded from Firebase) into collection View Cell on home Page

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, viewcontroller

Im trying to transfer an image between two view controllers. It is a profile image of the current logged in User, if there is one. The image is successful in downloading from Firebase. It downloads on a launch screen along with the username. If there is no user logged in, view controller changes to a login screen, if there is a logged in user it transfers to a home screen.
This is the launch screen. Both the username label and the image view are clear so user cannot see.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LaunchScreen: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!


var ref : DatabaseReference!
var storage: StorageReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    storage = Storage.storage().reference()

    checkUser()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func checkUser() {

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in



        if user != nil {
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            self.ref.database.reference().child("users/profile").child(uid!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let currentUser = dictionary["username"] as! String
                    let url = dictionary["photoURL"] as! String

                    let storageRef = self.storage.storage.reference(forURL: url)
                    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            self.reloadInputViews()
                        }
                    })


                    guard let image = self.userImage.image else {return}
                    self.usernameLabel.text = currentUser
                    let imageJPG = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                    print(imageJPG?.count)

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(self.usernameLabel.text, forKey: "user")
                    defaults.synchronize()


                }
            })
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })

            print("loggedIn")

        } else {
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
            let loginvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
            self.present( loginvc!,animated: true, completion: nil)

            })
            print("loggedOut")

        }


    }
}
```

}

This is my home page. where there is a side menu. the side menu pops open from the left hand side of the screen and on it are four collection view cells. the top one is the profile cell which will display the username and the user profile image. that image is where I want the downloaded Firebase userImage in launchScreenVC to be transferred too.

```
class home VC:  UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var profileMenuButton: UIButton!


   override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.reloadData()
    }



  let blackView = UIView()
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero , collectionViewLayout: layout )
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 50/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)
    return cv
}()

@IBAction func profileMenu() {

    let width = view.frame.width - 60



    collectionView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: view.frame.height)

    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))
    blackView.frame = view.frame
    blackView.alpha = 0
    view.addSubview(blackView)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.blackView.alpha = 1
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    }, completion: nil)
        handleSearchDismiss(searchView)


}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - (window.frame.width), y: 0, width: window.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }

        self.blackView.alpha = 0

    }
}
}

extension homeVC: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCellID", for: indexPath) as! profileCell
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        cell1.usernameLabel.text = (defaults.object(forKey: "user") as! String)
        cell1.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell1.usernameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
//            print(imageData)
//            cell1.profileImage.image = (defaults.object(forKey: "userImage") as! Data)


        return cell1
    } else if indexPath.item == 1{
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Settings", for: indexPath) as! settingsCell

        return cell2
    } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
        let cell3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Favourites", for: indexPath) as! favouritesCell

        return cell3
    } else {
        let cell4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Logout", for: indexPath) as! logoutCell

        return cell4
    }

 }
}
```

this is the profile cell class

```
class profileCell: UICollectionViewCell {



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpViews()
}

let profileImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    return imageView
}()

let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel()
    return label
}()

func setUpViews() {




    addSubview(profileImage)
    addSubview(usernameLabel)
    profileImage.frame = CGRect(x: (center.x)-60,  y: 30, width: 120, height: 120)
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = (profileImage.frame.width/2)
    usernameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: (center.x)-60, y: 125, width: 120, height: 120)
    usernameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}
```

Any Help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks Guys!

Comment: Instead of describing entire application structure, try to focus on a specific problem and only include code relevant to it. There are pages of code and its description posted, yet it's still not clear what your problem is.

Comment: You are not storing any image data in user-defaults and also that is not proper way to store your image for future use. Store only image `url` and where you actually need to show image use storage method to download image and show it into imageview.

Comment: There's entirely too much code in the question. Please take a moment and review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That being said, what's the actual issue? What do you mean *transfer an image between two view controllers*? If you have two view controllers, as long as they are aware of each other (i.e. the leftVC knows about the rightVC) or they have a parentVC, then an NSImage variable in one VC can be set by the other (or segue or representedObject etc)

Comment: @Jay well I've downloaded the image in the launch screen and I want it to show up in the home screen. I am not sure what a parentVC is or how to make the two View Controllers know about each other. What is an NSImage variable. Im also not using the storyboard.

Comment: A [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) is what  holds image data and an [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) would be used to display that image in the UI.If you set up a variable `let imageName = UIImage.Name("myImage.png")` then imageName holds a reference to that image and could be passed to another view controller. You may benefit from introductory programming tutorials to help understand vars, viewControllers etc. Check out [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/ios) tutorials. parentVC is a Parent ViewController.